# How to get text in EditText with ListView and adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, listadapter

I am having problem in getting text from EditText in the listview adapter. For example, when I click "9", it doesn't give me 9. Instead, I always get 3. I am unable to figure the reason behind this. Please inform me where I am going wrong.

This is my code for your perusal. Thank you in advance!

```
    class Planet {
    String name;
    int distance;
    String quantità;
    boolean selected = false;

        public Planet(String name, int distance, String quantità) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.distance = distance;
        this.quantità = quantità;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;

     }

    public int getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(int distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public String getQuantità() {
        return quantità;
    }

    public void setQuantità(String quantità) {
        this.quantità = quantità;
    }
    }

    public class PlanetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Planet>{
    private List<Planet> planetList;
    private Context context;
    ArrayList<Planet> objects;


    public PlanetAdapter(List<Planet> planetList, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.single_listview_item, planetList);
        this.planetList = planetList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public static class PlanetHolder {
        public TextView planetName;
        public TextView distView;
        public CheckBox chkBox;
        public EditText edit;
        public String quantità="3";
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        final PlanetHolder holder = new PlanetHolder();

        if(convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_listview_item, null);

            holder.planetName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.distView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dist);
            holder.chkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.chk_box);
            holder.edit = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText);


            holder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.edit.setEnabled(false);



            holder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener((MainActivity) context);

            //
            holder.chkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (holder.chkBox.isChecked()) {

                        holder.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.edit.setEnabled(true);



                        holder.edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                            @Override
                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                                holder.quantità = holder.edit.getText().toString();

                                System.out.println("leggo questo dalla edittext:"+ holder.edit.getText().toString());


                            }

                            @Override
                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                            }
                        });


                    } else {
                        holder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        holder.edit.setEnabled(false);
                        holder.edit.setText(null);

                    }
                }

            });


            } else {

        }


        Planet p = planetList.get(position);

        p.setQuantità(holder.quantità);



        holder.planetName.setText(p.getName());
        holder.distView.setText("" + p.getDistance());
        holder.chkBox.setChecked(p.isSelected());
        holder.chkBox.setTag(p);
        holder.edit.setEnabled(false);


        return v;
    }


    ArrayList<Planet> getBox() {
        ArrayList<Planet> box = new ArrayList<Planet>();
        for (Planet p : planetList) {
            if (p.selected)
                box.add(p);
        }
        return box;
    }

    }
```

Comment: Share code of the class and adapter.

Comment: please update your code by edit your question, do not it add in answer

Comment: i have this error:"it looks like your post is mostly code. please add some more details". why?

Comment: when you get the text in edittext (when your click on checkbox or ...)? why you know the  text that you get in editText is incorrect

Comment: i click on checkbox, so i put quantity and when i click on button "get answer" ,program doesn't take number that i put in editText

Comment: Your should write this line holder.quantità = holder.edit.getText().toString(); in afterTextChanged method instead of onTextChanged

Comment: @YasirTahir i have the same problem....

Comment: Have a look at my answer and accept it and up-vote my answer If I helped you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your getView() method with this:

```
 View row = convertView;
 PlanetHolder holder = null;
 if (row == null) {
     LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
     row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_listview_item, parent, false);
     holder = new PlanetHolder();
     holder.planetName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
     holder.distView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.dist);
     holder.chkBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.chk_box);
     holder.edit = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.editText);
     row.setTag(holder);
 } else {
     holder = (PlanetHolder) row.getTag();
 }
 final Planet p = planetList.get(position);

 holder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener((MainActivity) context);
 holder.chkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         if (holder.chkBox.isChecked()) {
             holder.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             holder.edit.setEnabled(true);
             holder.edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                 @Override
                 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                   p.setQuantità(holder.edit.getText().toString().trim());
                 }
             });
         } else {
             holder.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             holder.edit.setEnabled(false);
             holder.edit.setText(null);
         }
     }
 });
holder.planetName.setText(p.getName());
holder.distView.setText("" + p.getDistance());
holder.chkBox.setChecked(p.isSelected());
holder.chkBox.setTag(p);
holder.edit.setEnabled(false);

return row;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get text of your listview by this way, Use this in your activity or fragment. Here items is an arraylist.

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {

            View wantedView = recyclerView.getChildAt(i);
            EditText editqty = (EditText) wantedView.findViewById(R.id.edtTxtQty);
            if ((editqty.getText().toString().length() > 0)) {
               //store edit text value in any arraylist or array by editqty.getText().toString()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have fix value of `PlanetHolder` class so you always get value '3'

```
 public static class PlanetHolder {
    public TextView planetName;
    public TextView distView;
    public CheckBox chkBox;
    public EditText edit;
    public String quantità="3";
}
```

remove `public String quantità`fix value.

and Second is you have declare `View v = convertView;` but in if condition you can check this `if(convertView == null) {` so replace `convertView` to `v`